# Могут ли два деепричастия, отвечающих на разные вопросы, быть однородными членами конкретно в этом случае?

Tags: однородные-члены, деепричастия

Могут ли два деепричастия, отвечающих на разные вопросы, быть однородными членами конкретно в этом случае?

> — Неважно, что они думают, — ***положив*** кинжал на место и
> ***склонившись*** к брату, твердо заверил Джейс.

Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что к «положив кинжал» и «склонившись к брату» нужно задавать **разные** вопросы ? Какие именно, по Вашему мнению?

Comment: @Слава Здравствуйте. Склонившись отвечает на вопрос: что сделавши? 
Положив на вопрос: что сделав? Или в данном случае это вообще не имеет значение? Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думается мне, что все хорошо в этом предложении:
производитель действий **один**;
деепричастия относятся **к одному глаголу** и имеют один и тот же **вид** (положить — положив (что сделав?), склониться — склонившись (что сделавши?));
являются обстоятельствами времени (после чего — **когда?**).

Перестроим предложение:
Джейс положил кинжал на место, склонился к брату, твердо заверил...

Вот, считаю, интересный пример, в котором, правда, однородные деепричастные обороты разделены  глаголом (такое встречается нечасто):
*Седой Витюрка, **блаженно полуоткрыв рот,** сидел, **склонившись к гитаре,** тонкая счастливая нить слюны сползала на струны: он спал* (Владимир Маканин. Гражданин убегающий).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ и за приведенный пример! Действительно очень интересное предложение, впервые такое встречаю. Вы очень помогли с вопросом, еще раз благодарю!)